# How to install powershell on MacOS

Tags: macos, powershell, macos-high-sierra, powershell-core

I've installed the powershell PKG file and I can launch the powershell from Applications [image]

However, I would like to integrate it into the Terminal on Mac.

According to this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/267858/how-to-install-microsoft-powershell-on-linux-or-os-x/), after installing the pkg file i'm supposed to be able to run `powershell` command on terminal and switch into PS mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to run should be `pwsh` on macOS.

Comment: This is a recent change, with the formal release of PowerShell 6.0 for .Net Core. Earlier (pre-releases) and their documentation did say 'powershell' rather than 'pwsh'.